Unrecognized Imports in old Flask Project
I was working on setting up a flask web app today, and was referencing a previous ~2yr old project to refresh myself on some of the syntax and such. However, as I was looking through my (private) github repo for the project, I noticed a couple of imports in the project which I had never heard of / used before, and they seem to be entirely unused in the code.
Looking at the blame on github, they appear to be all from 1 commit, interspersed among changes that I certainly did make myself. Across 3 different files there were 4 unrecognized imports:
from unicodedata import category

from ast import Add
from wsgiref.handlers import BaseCGIHandler

and
from turtle import update

The project in question has only ever run locally on machines I personally own. I have no idea how these got there - should I be worried?

You were most likely experimenting with different tutorials and guides from the internet, added those imports and never used them. No need to worry

from unicodedata import category
from ast import Add
from wsgiref.handlers import BaseCGIHandler
from turtle import update

All those imports pertains to standard library (ast, wsgiref, turtle, unicodedata) so there should be not ModuleNotFoundErrors, which could happen if there would be some external package used. They should not affect further execution, if you do not make use of imported elements.

should I be worried?

Consult your's organization policy regarding code style. If usage of linter (for example pylint can report about unused-import) is stipulated you probably should delete unused imports, if they are reported by linter, which is kosher from organization point-of-view.
